# Add constant value to numeric XML attribute

Tags: regex, vim, editing, replace

### Background

Add a constant value to numbers matched with a regular expression, using vim (gvim).

### Problem

The following regular expression will match `width="32"`:

```
/width="\([0-9]\{2\}\)"
```

### Question

How do you replace the numeric value of the `width` attribute with the results from a mathematical expression that uses the attribute's value? For example, I would like to perform the following global replacement:

```
:%s/width="\([0-9]\{2\}\)"/width="\1+10"/g
```

That would produce `width="42"` for `width="32"` and `width="105"` for `width="95"`.

### Update

Looks like this cannot be done using regex alone -- is there a vim-way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%s/width="\zs\d\{2}\ze"/\=submatch(0)+10/g
```

See documentation for `/\zs`, `/\ze`, `sub-replace-expression` and `submatch()`.